# What do I put under A record apart from nameservers for hosted zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a domain registered with godaddy.

On AWS, I've set up the instance, load balancer with SSL, and a public hosted zone.

I tried inputting the nameservers but I still need to input an A record. The problem is that godaddy won't allow me to put in the A record provided by AWS (dualstack.acthttp-617756314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com.) instead it requires me to input an IP address only.

What value should I put for the A record, along with the 4 Route 53 nameservers to my domain point properly to my load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Route53 for the name servers, then setup the A record in Route53, not Godaddy. Route53 will allow you to setup an A record ALIAS that points to dualstack.acthttp-617756314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Thanks -- so does this mean I should input the nameservers provided by Route53 into Godaddy? If so, what would I put for the A record in Godaddy? The problem is godaddy only allows for an IP address as an A record so I cannot put the dualstack url provided by Route53.

Comment: You would disable Godaddy's DNS name servers, and configure Godaddy to respond with the Route53 name servers when your domain name is queried. At that point Route53 would be your DNS server. You would not create any A record on Godaddy at all. As I said in my answer "setup the A record in Route53, not Godaddy"